# npm tries to sign me up for private packages when publishing public packages

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a package `@myorg/somename` that has `private` set to `false`. When publishing the package with `npm publish` I get the error:

```
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ with tag latest and default access
npm ERR! code E402
npm ERR! 402 Payment Required - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@myorg%2fsomename - You must sign up for private packages
```

The package is Open Source, and **I explictly wish to publish the package publicly**. How can I publish the package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To publish a scoped package when you first publish it you need to run:

`npm publish --access=public`

You will not need to pass `--access=public` once its published there after.

Hope that helps